# Making map with gradation polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I am making a history map on my website these days. (http://eastmaps.com/2019/09/10/%ed%85%8c%ec%8a%a4%ed%8a%b8/ < it's my test version)

But like this site(https://www.ancient.eu/map/), I want to give gradation to the lines outside the polygon on the map.

I am using QGIS.

Do you know how to give a polygon gradation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a shapeburstfill to get this effect with QGIS (see animation below). You can set distance in mapunits or in screen units.

[image]

Comment: Oh my god! I didn't know what to do, but I solved the problem. Thank you very much for your quick reply :D